# Sort array in groups and people with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to sort an array into groups and people.

the problem is that it only shows me one person per class when I use the counter "pos_group = 0" but if I put it in negative and increase it in the "IF" if I get the result.

Am I doing something else in the assignment of the new array?

```
<?php

   $data = [
    0 => [
        'g_id' => 22,
        'g_name' => 'ABC',
        'u_id' => 1,
        'u_name'=> 'Pepe'
    ],
    1 => [
        'g_id' => 22,
        'g_name' => 'ABC',
        'u_id' => 2,
        'u_name'=> 'Mario'
    ],
    2 => [
        'g_id' => 22,
        'g_name' => 'ABC',
        'u_id' => null,
        'u_name'=> null
    ],
    3 => [
        'g_id' => 31,
        'g_name' => 'CDE',
        'u_id' => 3,
        'u_name'=> 'Juan'
    ],
    4 => [
        'g_id' => 41,
        'g_name' => 'EFG',
        'u_id' => 4,
        'u_name'=> 'Pedro'
    ],
    
];


    $last_group_id = null;
    $pos_group = 0;
    foreach ($data as $group_user):
        
        //Add Groups
        if($last_group_id != $group_user['g_id']){
            //$pos_group ++;
            $final[$pos_group]  = [
                'g_id' => $group_user['g_id'],
                'g_name' => $group_user['g_name']
            ];
            
            //$last_group_id = $group_user['g_id'];
            //$pos_group ++;
            
            
        }
        
        //Add Members
        if(!is_null($group_user['u_id'])){
            $final[$pos_group]['members'][$group_user['u_id']] = [
                'u_id' => $group_user['u_id'],
                'u_name' => $group_user['u_name']
            ];
        }

        if($last_group_id != $group_user['g_id']){
            $pos_group ++;
            $last_group_id = $group_user['g_id'];
        }
    endforeach;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final);
    //var_dump($final);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [g_id] => 22
            [g_name] => ABC
            [members] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [u_id] => 1
                            [u_name] => Pepe
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [u_id] => 2
                            [u_name] => Mario
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [g_id] => 31
            [g_name] => CDE
            [members] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [u_id] => 3
                            [u_name] => Juan
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [g_id] => 41
            [g_name] => EFG
            [members] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [u_id] => 4
                            [u_name] => Pedro
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I only get that result by setting the variable to -1 and increasing the counter after the "if", like this:

```
$last_group_id = null;
    $pos_group = -1;
    foreach ($data as $group_user):
        
        //Add Groups
        if($last_group_id != $group_user['g_id']){
            $pos_group ++;
            $final[$pos_group]  = [
                'g_id' => $group_user['g_id'],
                'g_name' => $group_user['g_name']
            ];
            
            $last_group_id = $group_user['g_id'];
            //$pos_group ++;
            
            
        }
        
        //Add Members
        if(!is_null($group_user['u_id'])){
            $final[$pos_group]['members'][$group_user['u_id']] = [
                'u_id' => $group_user['u_id'],
                'u_name' => $group_user['u_name']
            ];
        }

        // if($last_group_id != $group_user['g_id']){
        //     $pos_group ++;
        //     $last_group_id = $group_user['g_id'];
        // }
    endforeach;
```

It's a bit silly but I can't find the problem XD

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the position of your counter increment. The first case increments at the end of the loop, while the second one does it early in the loop. Let's observe what happens in the first case (incrementing at the end):

- first iteration

1. `$pos_group` is 0
2. a new group is added (with id 22) at index 0
3. a new member is added inside that group (Pepe)
4. `$pos_group` is incremented to 1

- second iteration

1. `$pos_group` is 1
2. group is not added as it is the same as the previous one
3. a new member is added (Mario), but at **index 1**, which places it **outside** the group (because the first member was added while `$pos_group` was 0)
4. `$pos_group` is **not** incremented

- third iteration

1. here no changes are made, group is the same and id is null

- fourth iteration

1. `$pos_group` is **still** 1 (no increment in last two iterations)
2. a new group is added at **index 1**, overwriting poor Mario
3. ...algorithm continues normally until the end...

So the discrepancy happens because the first two members of the group are added at different indices. Incrementing the `$pos_group` variable at the beginning, before any additions, removes the problem, thus giving correct result.

But I'd like to suggest a simplified algorithm for this purpose:

```
$final = [];
foreach ($data as $groupUser) {
    if (null !== $groupUser['u_id']) {
        /* Note that for the final array I use the group id as key. That way
        instead of tracking the current position and last group, you can simply
        add at the group id index. I am also overwriting the group info every time
        instead of checking if it exists (for simplicity), becuase there is no harm
        done since it will always be the same. */
        $final[$groupUser['g_id']]['g_id'] = $groupUser['g_id'];
        $final[$groupUser['g_id']]['g_name'] = $groupUser['g_name'];
        // add member, we've already checked the id against null
        $final[$groupUser['g_id']]['members'][$groupUser['u_id']] = [
            'u_id' => $groupUser['u_id'],
            'u_name' => $groupUser['u_name']
        ];
    }
}
```

No multiple checks, no additional variables to track, with the added benefit of working on unsorted data as well. The only difference is that my solution will have top level keys equal to group ids:

```
Array
(
    [22] => Array...
    [31] => Array...
```

If this is in any way a problem for you, all you have to do is grab `array_values($final)` to get a reindexed array, starting at 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is very well detailed. I made a version with the IDs and it worked fine but I forgot that there was a reindex function and I didn't want to go through the entire array with a foreach. Thank you so much!